# Docker Compose - https with Nginx/Gunicorn

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

I have the following Nginx config and docker-compose.yaml. Before I adding the following block,

```
server {

  listen 443;
  server_name localhost;

  ssl    on;
  ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/conf.d/privkey.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/conf.d/mynginx.key;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
}
```

everything thru HTTP works fine. After I added the above code block, everything stopped working, I can't access the site thru HTTP/HTTPS.

**docker-compose logs nginx** output

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?
```

**mynginx.conf**

```
upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

# portal
server {
  location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
  listen 8000;
  server_name localhost;
}



# portal (https)
server {

  listen 443;
  server_name localhost;

  ssl    on;
  ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/conf.d/privkey.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/conf.d/mynginx.key;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-9-162:~/django_docker$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: ng01
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: dg01
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn composeexample.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    expose:
      - "8000"

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: ps01
```

**Folder Structure**

```
.
├── config
│   ├── nginx
│   │   ├── mynginx.conf
│   │   ├── mynginx.conf~
│   │   ├── mynginx.crt
│   │   ├── mynginx.key
│   │   └── privkey.pem
│   └── requirements.pip
├── docker-compose.yml
├── docker-compose.yml~
├── Dockerfile
└── src
    ├── composeexample
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
    │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── settings.py~
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── db.sqlite3
    └── manage.py
```

Comment: So what's the error? Do you see something in nginx logs? `docker-compose logs nginx`

Comment: @Robert I'm getting "ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?"

Comment: It seems that you need to prepend sudo to the command.

Comment: @user1187968 I am experiencing the exact same issue. Did you solve it in any way?

Comment: The error was in  ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/conf.d/privkey.pem.